# How to read latest file created |pick the one is latest

Tags: linux

I have a folder in which files are created whenever I run my script. First time I run it creates `demo_1.txt`. Next time I run it creates `demo_2.txt`. And so on.

I want to read the latest created file based on timestamp.

If you see below the latest created file is `demo_4.txt` according to timestamp. That's the file I want to read.

```
demo_1.txt  => timestamp 8:00
demo_2.txt  => timestamp 8:02
demo_3.txt  => timestamp 8:03
demo_4.txt  => timestamp 8:04
```

This only half works. It reads *all* the files and appends them to `file.txt`.

```
find . -iname 'List*' -cm -60 -exec cat '{}' >> file.txt
```

How do I fix it to fetch just the latest file?

Comment: So regardless of the file's name, you want to extract the one that was **created** the last? What if the file was modified? Is the name of the file is a good indication about its **creation** time?

Comment: This might help! [Is it possible to reference the most recently modified file in a command line argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34736/is-it-possible-to-reference-the-most-recently-modified-file-in-a-command-line-ar)

Comment: Would `ls -t List* | head -1 | cat >> file.txt` do the job?

Answer (score 1):

```
stat * -c "%y-%n" | sort -r
```

Will list all the files in your current directory, sorted in descending order by time of last data modification.

If you just require the last modified file, the appropriate command would be

```
stat * -c "%y-%n" | sort -r | head -n 1
```

or

```
stat * -c "%y-%n" | tail -n 1
```